# Homestead and Laravel basis understanding

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead, laravel-artisan

I have some questions about the basis understanding about homestead and laravel.

I have set up my homestead with this guide: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead and it works ok.

1) But when I vagrant ssh into my box, I can call composer, but I can't call laravel or php artisan. Have I done something wrong/misunderstod something?

2) Do I need to install php and laravel locally, can't I just run it on my VM like i do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call `php artisan` commands (after you ran `vagrant ssh` command) you need to have installed Laravel project and you need to be in project's root folder:

```
cd my-laravel-project
php artisan
```

Comment: Thanks! That just shows my lack of understanding of how it works! I must keep on reading so I can understand this perfectly! 

However, my second question. Is there somethings I can do locally with laravel that I cant do with my homestead box?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your second question. Could you rephrase it please?

Comment: Yes, simulate the same environment your app will be hosted in... in reality, No, there isn't anything you can do locally that you cannot do in homestead.

Comment: @NicklasKevinFrank - thanks, that was what I ment:-)

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin - thanks for your help, sorry for my bad explanation:-)